# Package "nth" is in CTAN, but tlmgr doesn't find it

Tags: installing, texlive, ctan

I'm trying to install the `nth` package, which automatically adds and formats ordinal numbers in English.

The package is included in the default TeXLive distribution, but I had to install a smaller distribution on this computer for space considerations. So it should be in the repositories. When I ask `tlmgr` to install nth...

```
$ sudo tlmgr install nth
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
package nth not present in package repository.
```

Does it go by a different name than that in CTAN / the `tlmgr` repositories?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not all LaTeX packages have a dedicated TeX Live package. I find `nth` in the `genmisc` package for TeX Live.

Comment: That did it; I installed `genmisc` through `tlmgr` and that got it working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not all LaTeX packages have a dedicated TeX Live package for them. In particular, several small packages by Donald Arsenau are grouped together in a `genmisc` package. So

```
sudo tlmgr install genmisc
```

should solve the problem.

You can see it in the CTAN page: http://ctan.org/pkg/nth

[image]

Generally I recommend installing a full TeX Live and forget about hunting for packages; and updating regularly, also.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I normally would have installed the standard distribution (I did on my main computer), but in this case I had HDD space constraints and a very narrow, specific purpose for installing LaTeX.

Comment: Ah ha! Ran into this problem 4 years later, for a different reason: the default `texlive` package on Ubuntu doesn't include `genmisc`.